Homographic functional equation
My question is: what are applications of this functional equation $$f\left(\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}\right)=\frac{Af(x)+B}{Cf(x)+D}$$  Thank you in advance.

I guess you can obtain some complicated equations by substituting some values that has a cycle. I mean, you can get, for instance, 3 equations about $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, $f(b)$ and $f(c)$, $f(c)$ and $f(a)$ each.
